# Ideas needed for a sawdust collector

Tags: table-saw, dust

I am looking to minimize the the air borne dust created by the table saw.

Here is what I have that is relevant.

What can I do to make this work?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Using an idea posted, this is the starting point.

I will attach this to a plate that I will add to the bottom of the table saw.

[image]

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact  I have a shop vac. I need the dust collected as it is generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking how to fit dust collection to that old open contractor's saw...

For basic dust collection, you can get or make a fabric bag that attaches to the opening in that supporting plywood. Dust that would fall through now falls into the bag. That doesn't help with the dust being flung in other directions, but at least it saves some sweeping. The commercial versions of this have hardware that lets you snap the bag on and off, making emptying it somewhat more convenient.

For better dust collection, build a box which attaches to cover that opening and which has a hole or fitting where you can attach a shop vac's hose. Having that suction will gather more of the dust that would otherwise escape.

For better better dust collection, use a Dust Collector rather than a shop vac. The difference is basically that dust collectors are designed to generate less suction but move more air; that makes them better for this task. I've got a basic one with a 4"-diameter flexible hose that I move from tool to tool as needed; it works but came with a distinctly mediocre filter bag so is probably letting more fine dust back into the air than it should. As @Ecnerwal pointed out, filtering the air in the shop is one way to try to control that (and a good idea generally), but it's also possible to get higher-quality filters -- up to and including HEPA canister filters -- which will fit even a cheap dust collector and I expect to do that if/when I start generating more than trivial amounts of sawdust.

Comment: If you don't mind the dust outside a shop vac without a filter works great - maybe it will fail quicker but you can't beat the suction.  I also like the fleece bags you can put over the shop vac filters makes them quite a bit easier to clean.

Comment: @Fresh Codemonger Thanks for being so positive. My shop shop vacuum has a pleated filter. I am not familiar with those fleece bags.

Comment: +1 for the dust collector. Nothing else, even the shop vac, will move enough air to collect decent enough amounts of sawdust to keep the work area un-dusty. (20 years experience in a cabinet shop.)

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, buy a **dust collector** - they move **a lot** more air than a household vacuum and are made for the job.

Less ideally, but good enough for lots of people, use a **shop vacuum**, possibly with a **cyclone separator** ahead of it to drop most of the sawdust before the air hits the vacuum filter.

The handheld dustbuster-ish thing is just irrelevant to this job. The upright household vacuum is barely better; neither sucks enough air volume nor has sufficient collection volume to do the job effectively. You could try putting a cyclone separator ahead of the upright vac, but it will be disappointing, and far louder than a proper dust collector.

For fine dust in the air that has escaped initial collection, a filter with a fan recirculating air in the shop is standard. You'll have a lot of escaped dust if those are how you're attempting to vacuum sawdust from a tablesaw.

Comment: +1 for the cyclone bin between the TS and the shopvac. I've used this system in the past to good effect.

Comment: +1 for the dust collector and for making proper comment on the other vacuum selections. Best surgery is the swiftest, no matter how the patient feels about it.

Comment: If you go with a shop vac, which will be good but decent go with the cyclone separator between the saw and the vac, there are several avail  I like the Onieda one.   Also consider bags rather than filters.  I use them and while a bit pricey, because the entire surface of the bag is porous you get full suction even when full.   With a separator the bag should last a  very long time.   Here's a link:  https://www.lowes.com/pd/Shop-Vac-2-Pack-14-Gallon-Dry-Collection-Bag/5013192255?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-tol-_-ggl-_-LIA_TOL_129_Power-Tools-_-5013192255-_-local-_-0-_-0&ds_rl=1286981&gclsrc=ds

Answer (score 2):

It's called Craigslist -> search for "Dust Collector" -> contact the people -> go, try, buy or not, take home.  To fund it, list the things in your photos on Craigslist. Solved. **Fooling around with things that are not dust collectors is a certified waste of your time**.

Now, to modify the saw for a dust collector, I've seen exactly this done on a similar saw. Plywood panels were cut which fit the bottom and 4 sides of the metal stand.  One side had an openable door you could get into to remove the sawdust.

Think about where the saw will tend to throw sawdust (or just run the saw for awhile and learn where inside the box it tends to throw sawdust). Find a place *far from there* where you can cut either a round or oval opening.  Go to an old school family owned lumberyard and look at wood stove flue fittings, and find something that will provide a port for the dust collector hose, and provides a round or oval opening you can dock up to the plywood.   Hook all that up.

Now some sawdust will stay in this box, and it'll tend to be the heavier stuff... other sawdust including most of the fines will be sucked into the dust collector. There will be a strong downdraft at the saw slot so that should contain most sawdust and greatly reduce your room dust.

Make sure to vent the dust collector outside.  Keep it will be ejecting conditioned air, causing fresh air to be sucked into the room and your heater or A/C will have to work harder to keep the room warm/cool.